# kafka restabilizing group using spring kafka consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, spring-kafka

I have a quite slow consumer which could take more than 5 minutes to process the record. What I want to avoid is kafka restabilizing the group.
In order to do this from my understanding I have to set to the kafka broker the following properties:

```
  group.max.session.timeout.ms = 3600001 
  group.min.session.timeout.ms = 3600000
```

In my application side I have the following configuration :

```
    @Bean
      public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        final Map<String, Object> propsMap = new HashMap<>();
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
            environment.getProperty("app.kafkaBrokers"));
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "100");
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, Integer.valueOf(environment.getProperty("app.session.timeout.ms")) );
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, Integer.valueOf(environment.getProperty("app.session.timeout.ms")) + 1 );
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group1");
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
        return propsMap;
      }

@Bean
  KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
        new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency(9);// was 3
    factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(3000);
    return factory;
  }
```

And also in my listener I have:

```
 @KafkaListener(id = "baz", topics = "tipJobsForExecution", containerFactory="kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
  public void listen(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record)
```

My listener takes about 5 minutes to process the messages. As soon as it finished I read the following at kafka broker side:

> 2018-05-03 10:29:11,210] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Preparing to
>   rebalance group baz with old generation 22 (__consumer_offsets-7)
>   (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)

From my understanding kafka consideres the consumer dead and rebalances the group. My question is why is this happenning ? 
One idea that I have is that maybe the heartbeat is not heartbeating every  3000ms as it should but I do not know how troubleshout this.

Thanks in advance,
Giannis

Answer (score 4):

You have to be aware of three types of timeout configuration parameters for Kafka consumer.

**heartbeat.interval.ms** - The expected time between heartbeats to the consumer coordinator when using Kafka's group management facilities. Typically should be 1/3 of the session.timeout value Default value - 3000 ms

**session.timeout.ms** - If no heartbeats are received by the broker before the expiration of this session timeout, then the broker will remove this consumer from the group and initiate a re-balance.Default value 10000

**max.poll.interval.ms** -  If poll() is not called before expiration of this timeout, then the consumer is considered failed and the group will re-balance
Default value - 300000

In your case it looks like the poll interval is set to a too low value.

Reference - https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#newconsumerconfigs

Comment: hi asolanki, I was about to say that this fixed the issue. But as soon as I read the last message from kafka I get the following error on the broker side: Member consumer-19-c627afe5-51d0$40df-9857-6e39816116ca in group baz has failed, removing it from the group (kafka.coo$dinator.group.GroupCoordinator) 
Since this is an info can it be considered safe because the message appeared as soon as I read the last message?

Comment: The consumer failure could be because of several reasons. The consumer keep calling poll at the frequency of poll timeout whether or not there are message in topic.